# Increasing Malt Aroma

Tags: beer, malt, aroma

How does one get more malt aroma out of a recipe? 
 If I want more roasty aroma I know I can add more roasted malt.  But eventually, there is appoint where I can't have too much or the recipe itself suffers.

Are there any process steps to be taken that can increase maltiness, toastiness, etc etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get more malt flavour and aroma to come through by substituting some of the base malt with munich.

Similar to no-sparge, [partigyle](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Parti-gyle) brewing will create a rich malty brew from the first runnings, but you get better utilization of the grain compared to no-sparge, since there is also the second runnings.

Other alternatives:

- add chlorides (50-100ppm) to emphasize the malt character (and correspondingly reduce sulphates to lessen the hop character)
- use less hops to avoid masking the malt flavour and aroma
- use a yeast strain that is known to produce malty beers, such as Scottish Ale and Munich Lager yeasts.

These changes have to be made with the target style in mind and probably work best with malt-forward styles to avoid going out of style. But not that it matters so much, you'll still end up with a tasty brew.

Answer (score 3):

[No-sparge](http://www.promash.com/tipsntricks/CommonTasks/MechOfNoSparge.html) is one approach, the lack of sparge creates richer malt flavors. Another is to use malts that boost malt aroma: [Aromatic Malt](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Aromatic_malt), [Melanoidin Malt](http://www.brew-dudes.com/melanoidin-malt/226), etc. [Decoction Mashing](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Decoction_mash) can boost malt flavors, although I've never tried it.

And some yeast strains are better than others at producing maltiness. I recently did a split batch of four English yeast strains (Wyeast 1968, 1338, 1318 and 1187). All created very different malt flavors.

And, of course, proper treatment of the finished beer helps. Aromas will dissipate and flavors will oxidize if the beer is treated roughly.

Comment: I agree with the yeast selection point.   I used Wyeast 3725 (Biere De Garde) for 3 brews this year, and each of them had quite accentuated malt flavors.   Though they were all malt-forward styles.